# st_mtimensec not available in struct stat

Tags: c, mips, cross-compiling, stat, uclibc

I'm trying to compile [Evas](http://docs.enlightenment.org/auto/evas/) for the host **mipsel-linux-uclibc**. I'm using an old binary toolchain from my company to do it. It was compiled around 2008 and I'm kinda stuck with it right now. Looks like this toolchain is missing the following field in the struct stat of stat.h:

```
unsigned long int st_mtimensec; /* Nsecs of last modification.  */
```

The closest thing that I have is:

```
__time_t st_mtime;      /* Time of last modification.  */
```

Looks like this is related to uclibc. Is there an easy way out of this?

Comment: Maybe uclibc doesn't think it can provide better resolution than 1 second?  Edit: I just downloaded a recent version of uclibc, and that field is there.  What version are you using?  You should be able to link against your own uclibc regardless of what toolchain you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct stat` is *supposed* to contain a member `struct timespec st_mtim;` and `stat.h` is *supposed* to `#define st_mtime st.mtim.tv_sec`. If your uClibc is too old to have these right, you could try hacking them into the header (there's probably just a `time_t st_mtime;` member and a padding member next to it where the nanoseconds should be). The important thing is that you **must** keep the layout of the members (their offsets in the structure) the same or things will horribly break.

A better question might be why Evas isn't portable to older (pre-POSIX-2008) systems, and why it's using the wrong name for the nanoseconds field (the correct name is `st_mtim.tv_nsec`, not `st_mtimensec`. The most beneficial course of action would probably be to get these fixes upstream in Evas so other users won't encounter problems in the future.